# Visual Studio Code terminal does not work properly if launched using the `code .` command on macOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

If I launch Visual Studio Code using the dock in macOS the terminal works normally.

But if I launch Visual Studio Code from the command line:

```
% vscode .
```

Then the terminal control characters do not work properly. Instead of controlling the command line cursor they print:

[image: Preview]

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the TERM variable in your terminal, prior to executing code? Compare that with the TERM that is used to execute an application from the dock, and you may find your answer. I'm not sure if macOS utilizes the "defaults" list for terminals and docks commands, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Visual Studio Code 1.59.0 on Big Sur.

I configure PATH from VSC IDE with CMD+SHIFT+P : `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH`

From the Terminal I run `code` to start the application and I have no issues.

Comment: Wow. That worked. Thanks.  I had it installed on the path but not from within VSCode.